# How to create meta tags dynamically in BigCommerce?

Tags: seo, bigcommerce

Is there any way that we can create meta tags for products dynamically in Bigcommerce? I have to write meta tags for 3000 product pages of a website using Bigcommerce, so it would be of great help if there is a way to create meta tags dynamically.

Comment: I suppose it depends on what exactly you are hoping to accomplish. Feel free to clarify more, but generally your best bet is to create them offline using Excel, Access or otherwise and then import them back into Bigcommerce.

Comment: Meta tags for what? Products? Categories? Web Pages? If it's just products, export to a CSV file and run it through your favorite spreadsheet editor.

Comment: @developerscott What I want to accomplish is, anything that takes product name as Title tag and product description as Meta Description tag automatically. If there is any BigCommerce API or so which takes these automatically and create meta tags, then it will really help a lot.

Comment: @TheEks yes, it is products.

Comment: Product name is automatically included in the title tag unless you override it with the SEO title option. For meta descriptions I think it is omitted if it is not set in the admin, which means Google will use the content (i.e. the product description). So I don;t see any benefit in automatically setting the seo title and meta description to what Google will use already.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are just looking to generate meta data for product, you can use the export functionality of Bigcommerce, modify the CSV file that is generated with you favorite spreadsheet editor, and then reimport to Bigcommerce. They have a [guide for the import/export tools](https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/How-do-I-import-products-and-product-options-with-a-CSV-file/)

Comment: @NiravParmar no problem. Remember to mark this as a correct answer if it helps to resolve your issue.